# How to remove Profile Picture section or the message "You can change your profile picture on Gravatar."

Tags: customization, custom-field

How to remove profile picture section from WordPress admin panel or the link "You can change your profile picture on Gravatar."

```
add_action('admin_footer-profile.php', 'remove_profile_fields');
function remove_profile_fields()
{
    if(current_user_can('custom_role'))
    { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
var hideFields = [ "aim", "yim", "jabber" ];
jQuery.each( jQuery( "form#your-profile tr" ), function() {
    var field = jQuery( this ).find( "input,textarea,select" ).attr( "id" );
    if ( hideFields.indexOf( field ) != -1 ) {
        jQuery( this ).remove();
    }
});
/* ]]> */</script>
<?php }
}
```

I'd tried above code but it is not working at all.

Comment: Don't scream for help, just ask a proper question and someone will answer when your question if they have time ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To remove the profile picture row of the table (which includes the gravatar link):

```
jQuery( "tr.user-profile-picture" ).remove();
```

To remove that entire "about yourself" table:

```
jQuery( "tr.user-profile-picture" ).parents("table:first").remove();
```

Use this type of jQuery call, don't try to get fancy with the loop.
This is on WP 4.4; earlier versions may have different HTML class names for those elements.